# Weld verticies in 3D Studio Max

Tags: 3ds-max, modeling

So I have four splines (not the same object) in 3D Studio Max and I need to weld the vertices to make them one spline.

Is this even possible? How?

[image: Splines]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured it out,... use the Attach multiple, then select the objects to attach.

Comment: If this answer suits your needs, then please mark this question as answered.